# Is there something that lookaheads do to the normal part of a regex?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I was trying to use lookaheads in my code to try to apply a function to all numbers in a string, but when I tried to add a lookahead to prevent random words with numbers in them (like models of things) the regex only gets the last whole interger (in this case, 9) and adds the decimals. I assume I'm doing something wrong with adding the lookahead, but I couldnt find anything on it. The length of the numbers varies, so using curly brackets isn't an option. What am I doing wrong?

```
e = "59.84"
ea = e.replace(/(?!\w\-*\d+\.?\d*\w)\-?\d+\.*\d*/g, v => v * 2 );
console.log(ea)/*logs... 519.68???
5 + 9.84 * 2
*/

e = "59.84"
ea = e.replace(/\-?\d+\.?\d*/g, v => v * 2 );
console.log(ea)/*logs 119.68*/
```

Comment: Maybe you missed that  `\w` also matches digits? The negative lookahead prevents a match at the very first position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The look-ahead pattern `\w\-*\d+\.?\d*\w` matches at the first position:

- `\w` matches with `5`
- `-*` is a zero length match
- `\d+` matches with `9`
- `\.?` matches with `.`
- `\d*` matches with `8` (after trying first with `84` and backtracking)
- `\w` matches with `4`

And since this is a *negative* look ahead, there cannot be a match at the first position, even though the "normal" part would match. The initial digit `5` in the input will not be replaced. The first possible match starts at the next position.

I think your main mistake was to think that `\w` would only match Latin letters and not digits, but it does match with digits too.

To avoid matching numbers that are pre- or postfixed by letters, you can use:

```js
var e = "59.84  test91.23  53.66test ok:12.34.";
var ea = e.replace(/(?<!\w)\-?\d+(\.\d*(?!\w)|(?![\w.]))/gi, v => v * 2 );
console.log(ea);
```